# Primes such that $a_p=0$ for a particular elliptic curve

Tags: number-theory, elliptic-curves

**Some context**

It can be proved that for the elliptic curve given by $E :y^2 = x^3-x$, the number of points of $E$ in $\Bbb P^2(\Bbb F_p)$, denoted by $|E(\Bbb F_p)|$, is $p+1$ if and only if $p \equiv 3 \pmod 4$ (where $p>3$ is a prime number).
In other words, the set
$$S(E) := \{p \text{ prime numbers } \;:\; |E(\Bbb F_p)|=p+1\}$$
is equal to the set of the prime numbers of the form $P(n)=3n+4$.

However, I was wondering what happens for a different elliptic curve, namely $$E : y^2=x^3+5x+1.$$
The first primes $p$ such that $|E(\Bbb F_p)|=p+1$ are $5,131,193,521,1987,2089,2161,2503,2803,5189,6737,…$ and OEIS didn't give anything. Apparently, we can't find any "easy" congruence modulo some integer to list such primes, i.e. I think that these primes *can't* be represented as $an+b$ for fixed $a,b$, as $n≥N$ goes through $\Bbb N$ (for $N$ large enough). Whence the following question:

**Question**

> Is there a polynomial $P \in \Bbb Z[X]$ with positive coefficients and a positive integer $N \in \Bbb N$, such that
>   $$S(E) \cap \Bbb P_{≥N} = \{P(k) \mid k \in \Bbb N \} \cap \Bbb P_{≥N} $$
>   where $\Bbb P_{≥N}$ denotes the set of prime numbers greater that $N$ and $E : y^2=x^3+5x+1$ ?

In the previous example, we had $P(X)=3X+4$ and $N=5$. I am aware that this may be a difficult question, so I would be also interested in references about "polynomial growth" of the primes such that $a_p:=p+1-|E(\Bbb F_p)|=0$ ([supersingular primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supersingular_prime_(for_an_elliptic_curve)) ?) for a given elliptic curve.

Thank you very much!

Comment: well the first curve has complex multiplication by $\Bbb Z[i]$ so there is a lot of good things we can say about the frobenius maps and so about $a_p$

Comment: @mercio : thank you very much for your comment! I don't know complex multiplication, but is it possible to prove for instance that the second curve admits no CM? Or is it a difficult problem in general?

Comment: it doesn't admit CM, see http://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q/8432/a/1

Comment: @mercio : thank you! Do you have a reference dealing with the relation between CM and the "good things" we can say about $a_p$ ?

Comment: it's contingent to the explicit class field theory for imaginary quadratic fields. See for example Goro Shimura's book 
"Introduction to the Arithmetic Theory of Automorphic Functions"

Comment: see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/842952/number-of-points-on-an-elliptic-curve-over-mathbbf-q/843044#843044 and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/742066/the-group-structure-of-elliptic-curve-over-mathbb-f-p/742280#742280 for examples of those good things

Comment: Related: https://usamo.wordpress.com/2015/07/05/linniks-theorem-for-sato-tate-laws-on-cm-elliptic-curves/ (Theorem 3, but for CM elliptic curves...). Maybe also related : https://mathoverflow.net/questions/11688/why-do-congruence-conditions-not-suffice-to-determine-which-primes-split-in-non ?